# How to restore (predict) data based on correlation/regression in Excel?

Tags: excel, regression, correlation, predict

I have some data in which a feature (height) is correlated with output variable (price). How to restore missing data (nulls) in height feature based on existing dependancy (correlation) between these variables?

To be more clear:
[image]

Input and output variables have clear correlation. I guess that predicting missing values for excel is not a difficult procedure. But I need some directions how to implement it.

Comment: Actually this is interesting. You'd  have to take Height as your known y and Price as your known x and it does give slightly different results to doing it the other way round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you got the slope (m) and intercept (c) of the regression line in E2 and E3 (say):-

```
=SLOPE(C2:C9,B2:B9)

=INTERCEPT(C2:C9,B2:B9)
```

you could re-arrange the simple regression equation y=mx+c to predict the x-values

```
x=(y-c)/m
```

So your predicted heights would be:-

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),(C2-E$3)/E$2,B2)
```

starting in D2.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might try the [FORECAST¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/FORECAST-function-50CA49C9-7B40-4892-94E4-7AD38BBEDA99). The first blank does not have enough preceding data to generate a forecast result so a simple ratio will have to suffice but the remaining values can be generated and take previously generated FORECAST results into consideration for their own result(s).

[image: FORECAST_Height]

The formula in E2 is,

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2), FORECAST(C2, B$2:B$9, C$2:C$9), B2)
```

---

¹ <sub>See [Forecasting functions](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Forecasting-functions-897a2fe9-6595-4680-a0b0-93e0308d5f6e) for alternative algorithms in data prediction.</sub>

Comment: @pnuts - I played with it to try and get a better result for the **3.13/14000** without success. If `=IF(ISBLANK(B2), FORECAST(C2, B$2:B$9, C$2:C$9),  B2)` is used, the 3.13 becomes 2.95 (better) and 2.75 becomes 2.64 (worse).

Comment: Well, I finally saw that the **2.64/11000** wasn't out-of-place like I originally thought. I've removed the progression in favor of a more conventional 'full-column' FORECAST. Thanks for making me take a second look.